# Scan files in a Directory - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, directory, load, scanning

I am trying to load files from my directory with matlab. The code is fairly simple :

```
for j =1:8
    people_names=dir('~/Desktop/Directory/Data/*.mat');
    people_name=people_names(j).name
    resp=load('~/Desktop/Directory/Data/people_name');
```

However, the load command fail because it reads "people_name" as a string and not its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'oh.  Your first statement in your `for` loop should be **outside** of it.  You want to find all files first, *then* loop over each file.  You're doing that inside your loop statement, and that will probably not give you what you want.

You also are using `load` wrong.  You'd want to use the actual string of `people_name` itself.  You also will want to loop over all possible file names, not just the first 8:

```
people_names=dir('~/Desktop/Directory/Data/*.mat'); %// Change

for jj = 1:numel(people_names) %// Change

    people_name=people_names(jj).name;
    resp=load(people_name); %// Change

    %// Rest of your code here....
    %//...
end
```